# How do I init an array with non fixed length in a C++ class?

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I'm just starting C++ and I'm trying to init an array in a class with a length depending on the "s" parameter. Can someone tell me the easiest way to do this?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Game{
    public:
        int size;
        int grid[size][size]; // This is where the error occurs.
        Game(int s){
            size = s;
        }

};

int main(){
    Game g(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The moment you say "non-fixed", equate that to *dynamic container*. The most common is `std::vector`. In your case, `std::vector<std::vector<int>> grid;` would probably do what you want, initialized by `Game(int s) : grid(s, std::vector<int>(s)) {}`

Comment: Do note that `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` is not a "2D array", but a scattered array of arrays. It is **very** inefficient and it does not maintain basic invariants by itself (such as "all lines have the same number of columns"). A proper solution is to create a simple 2d array class.

Comment: There is no way to "init an array with non fixed length in C++" for the simple reason that there is no such thing as a "array with non fixed length in C++". C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Right, in c++ when you need an array whose size is not known at compile time you generally use `std:vector`, a 2D grid doesn't necessarily need to nest them, you'll find a lot of answers on similar questions here. In c++ *init*, *declare* and *define* means different things, my advice is to learn the basics on a good book before acquiring bad habits

Comment: I agree with @spectras: a wrapper class over `std::vector` is the most feasible solution. Be noted though, that all N-dimensional arrays are actually backed by RAM, which is basically a big 1D-array, so resizing an arbitrarily sized N-dimension would have an overhead of reallocating storage(s) and moving elements around to a new layout. In case of square/cube/hypercube array, it may be greatly optimized by placing each new row/column entirely into trailing part of backing vector.

Answer (score 5):

Use a `std::vector`, and consider mapping the 2D into 1D.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cassert>

using std::cout;
using std::ostream;
using std::size_t;
using std::vector;

class Game {
    size_t size;
    vector<int> grid; // vector will be size * size big.
public:
    Game(size_t s) : size{s}, grid(s * s, 0) { }

    auto operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const -> int {
        assert(x < size);
        assert(y < size);
        auto i = x + y * size;
        return grid[i];
    }

    auto operator()(size_t x, size_t y) -> int& {
        assert(x < size);
        assert(y < size);
        auto i = x + y * size;
        return grid[i];
    }

    void print(ostream&) const;
};

void Game::print(ostream& out) const {
    auto end = size * size;
    auto sep = "";

    for (size_t i = 0; i < end; ++i) {
        out << sep << grid[i];
        sep = ((i + 1) % size == 0) ? "\n" : " ";
    }

    out << "\n";
}

int main() {
    Game g(10);
    g(0, 3) = 9;
    g(5, 5) = 5;
    g.print(cout);
}
```